# Javadoc for JavaFX (not JavaFX api!); from source? from project scenegraph?

Tags: java, javadoc, javafx, scenegraph

The API JavaFX comes with is for the JavaFX langage, which I have one reason to learn, but more reasons not to. I know Project Scenegraph (scenegraph.dev.java.net, AKA Scenario) is ambiguously the same library. I would just generate javadocs from Project Scenegraph, but it hasn't seen an update since 2007 and the mailing lists are dead.

Does anyone know of a download for the JavaFX javadocs, or a way to download the source in order to generate them myself?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX uses scenegraph at the core for the UI, but JavaFX is a lot more than just scenegraph.

Comment: Does JavaFX really use a project that is gathering three years of dust and hasn't reached 1.0? I'm incredulous at either possibility, that A) they're developing scenegraph for JavaFX without releasing the source, or B) they're basing JavaFX on a library they're letting die.

Comment: I don't understand your assertion. Scenegraph is alive and evolving fast. You might want to follow http://www.svjugfx.org/calendar/12863551/ for an update fairly soon.